# Reg expression, from every word in sentence, get everything until the 4th slash of that word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Best

I would like to have a reg expression which transforms the next sentence

```
heb/MD/B-VP/O/hebben ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik zitten/MD/B-VP/O/zitten slapen/VB/I-VP/O/slapen ?/./O/O/?
of/CC/O/O/of heb/MD/B-VP/O/hebben ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik het/PRP/I-NP/O/het samenwonen/NN/I-NP/O/samenwonen zo/RB/B-ADJP/O/zo lang/JJ/I-ADJP/O/lang uitgesteld/VBN/B-VP/O/uitstellen omdat/CC/O/O/omdat ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik het/PRP/I-NP/O/het onbewust/JJ/B-ADJP/O/onbewust niet/RB/B-ADVP/O/niet wil/MD/B-VP/O/willen ?/./O/O/?
ben/MD/B-VP/O/zijn ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik wel/RB/B-VP/O/wel gaan/MD/I-VP/O/gaan houden/VB/I-VP/O/houden van/IN/B-PP/O/van haar/MD/B-VP/O/haren ,/,/O/O/, maar/CC/O/O/maar niet/RB/B-ADVP/O/niet van/IN/B-PP/B-PNP/van haar/PRP$/B-NP/I-PNP/haar -/./O/O/- echte/JJ/B-ADJP/O/echt -/./O/O/- leven/NN/B-NP/O/leven ?/./O/O/?
http:&slash;&slash;www.google.be&slash;test/NNP/B-NP/O/http://www.google.be/test
```

Into, this desired result:

```
hebben ik zitten slapen ? of hebben ik het samenwonen zo lang uitstellen omdat ik het onbewust niet willen ? zijn ik wel gaan houden van haren , maar niet/ van haar - echt - leven ? http://www.google.be/test
```

Therefore, I would like to select **"each word"** (e.g. *heb/MD/B-VP/O/hebben*) ->  *([^\s]+)* and take all the characters (**a-z&é"'(§234567etc"**) until the 4th slash (**heb/MD/B-VP/O/**).

In such a way that I can replace those matches by " "

Kind regards

Comment: shouldn't your output look more like `hebben ik zitten slapen ....`, right now there doesn't seem to be a correlation between your input, expression, and output

Comment: @depperm, you were correct: i had the wrong out or in-put  but  the context stays the same. Basically how do you narrow a reg-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `([^\/]+\/){4}` which looks for 4 segments of at least one non `\` followed by a `\`. Then after splitting the input by whitespace you repace that pattern for each word with an empty string.

```
import re

input_str='heb/MD/B-VP/O/hebben ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik zitten/MD/B-VP/O/zitten slapen/VB/I-VP/O/slapen ?/./O/O/? of/CC/O/O/of heb/MD/B-VP/O/hebben ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik het/PRP/I-NP/O/het samenwonen/NN/I-NP/O/samenwonen zo/RB/B-ADJP/O/zo lang/JJ/I-ADJP/O/lang uitgesteld/VBN/B-VP/O/uitstellen omdat/CC/O/O/omdat ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik het/PRP/I-NP/O/het onbewust/JJ/B-ADJP/O/onbewust niet/RB/B-ADVP/O/niet wil/MD/B-VP/O/willen ?/./O/O/? ben/MD/B-VP/O/zijn ik/PRP/B-NP/O/ik wel/RB/B-VP/O/wel gaan/MD/I-VP/O/gaan houden/VB/I-VP/O/houden van/IN/B-PP/O/van haar/MD/B-VP/O/haren ,/,/O/O/, maar/CC/O/O/maar niet/RB/B-ADVP/O/niet van/IN/B-PP/B-PNP/van haar/PRP$/B-NP/I-PNP/haar -/./O/O/- echte/JJ/B-ADJP/O/echt -/./O/O/- leven/NN/B-NP/O/leven ?/./O/O/? http:&slash;&slash;www.google.be&slash;test/NNP/B-NP/O/http://www.google.be/test'

regex=re.compile(r'([^\/]+\/){4}')
s=[]
for word in input_str.split():
  s.append(regex.sub('',word))
print(' '.join(s))
```